# Detecting whether multiple browsers/tabs are opened with django

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions, browser-tab

I am developing web pages that I need that won't be opened in more then one browser/browser tab. Only one tab in one browser for one client.

I know that it is possible in the modern web, because I see that websites like Netflix does that.

What is the required setup for this? Can this be done with bare django?

Comment: Can be done using websockets whereby you can monitor currently opened connections. If more than one websocket is open, then you know that user has opened multiple tabs.

Comment: You can also try to devise a mechanism using browsers's localStorage. One posiible solution is, you can set current timestamp in an interval, and when opening a page, check that value in localStorage and possibly block it depending on the value in local storage

Comment: Using websockets, how the server know that two sockets are from the same machine? With IP address? If yes it is a problwm since multiple machines can be connected with the same IP